# unexpected type error

Tags: java

I'm new at Java, I study on strings and i want a string to be reversed. Here is my code

```
String myStr = "abcdef"; String reversed = "";
for(int j=myStr.length()-1;j>=0;j--) {
    myStr.charAt(j) += reversed;
}
```

But it gives me an error message:

```
****.java:14: error: unexpected type
required: variable
found:    value
```

But when I print it by `System.out.print(reversed)`, it prints `reversed` correctly. What is the difference between variable and value? Why it can give me correct answer in spite of giving me an error message? I'll appreciate your answers, thanks

Comment: How can it print anything if it doesn't compile in the first place?

Comment: It gives me and error message in build output something like unexpected type

Comment: There is a "ters" variable calling ".length()" which I assume should be "myStr"?

Comment: @brainzzy I've just made the correction, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
myStr.charAt(j) += reversed;
```

The left-hand-side is a value. Not a variable. That's why you can't to a `+=` to it.

---

Although it defeats the purpose of learning how do it the hard way, you can do it like this:

```
myStr = new StringBuffer(myStr).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

it sould be `reversed += new String(myStr.charAt(j));` ... the unexpected type is that what charAt(j) returns

Comment: oh ... yes ... using `... += new String(...)` within a loop is very bad idea ... use a StringBuilder instead and its method .append(char).

Answer (score 1):

```
String myStr = "abcdef";
String reversed = "";

for(int j = myStr.length()-1 ; j >= 0; j--)
{
     reversed += myStr.CharAt(j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`+=` works on a variable not a value. `myStr.charAt(j)` returns a value, and you can't use `+=` on that value. It has to be some variable like `reversed`.
e.g.

```
reversed += myStr.substring(j, j+1);
```

Comment: I was just explaing the error message. That it's like doing `5 += 1;` instead of `int a = 5; a += 1;`. But,  I have also added the solution to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `reversed += myStr.charAt(j)`. You can only assign a value to a variable. `myStr.charAt(j)` is not a variable. It's an expression that returns a value or type char.

You should also use a `StringBuilder` and append each char to the StringBuilder, because your loop creates a new String instance at each iteration, which is not efficient at all.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are places where you can store values. They must be declared and assigned a value before being used:

```
String reversed = "";
```

`reversed` is a variable assigned the value `""`.
Only variables may be on the left side of an assignment (such as `=`). `+=` is a special type of assignment. `a += b;` is basically the same as `a = a + b;`.

Values are the results of expressions. Expressions are things like variable references (`reversed`), constants (`""`), method calls (`myStr.charAt(0)`), and operations (`a + b`). Values can be on the right side of an assignment.

I'm not sure why it is giving you the correct answer, as the code shouldn't run at all when you have a compile error like that.

Comment: yeah, it gives me a correct string what I expected, but also I'm confused about that error, is it something like compiler's auto-correction?

Comment: Now that I think about it, it may be that the .class file was never overwritten because your compile error prevented the output of a new .class file. If you had a correctly working version before, it could be running that. Try changing the input myStr and see if it outputs the new correct answer.

Comment: wow, I've just changed input and re-build. Yeah, it is not running. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

"**unexpected type**" error can happen if you screw up a "**Yoda Expression**":

---

**Example**:

---

```
if(null= my_variable){}; //:WRONG#1 (malformed yoda expression)
if(null==my_variable){}; //:CORRECT
if(my_variable= null){}; //:WRONG#2 (for completeness of example)
```

**Result** ( WRONG#1 ):

> unexpected type [ERROR]
>   required: variable [ERROR]
>   found:    value

**Result** ( WRONG#2 ):

> incompatible types: TYPE_OF_MY_VARIABLE_HERE cannot be converted to boolean